# Backlight control with 2.4 Inch display

Tags: led, touchscreen, screen

I have 2.4 Inch display attached to a Raspberry Pi 3B+, it totally works, but I've noticed that when raspbian turn off the display, the backlight led is still on.

**There is a way to control the backlight led?** *I've read that other 2.4 Inch displays have a BL Jumper but this doesn't.*

I only have this documentation about my display.
http://www.lcdwiki.com/2.4inch_RPi_Display_For_RPi_3A%2B

Comment: well, that documentation doesn't mention any control of backlight LED, so it seems there's no control available

Comment: oh ok, I posted this question only if someone had some easy hack to do this, but if this is not possible then I'll let the led on, btw it's a led there is no high consumption on this.

Answer (score 1):

I've found someone that was doing the same that I want to do.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=149887

[image]

I'll try it to see if I can make that switch to work with my model.

Comment: it's a complicated design, hmm... this gives a clue about how to do the led switch, but I need to dismantle my screen and it's not worth it. I think if someone wants to experiment with the screen this can give a clue.